# access to entity join result by foreach?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity

i have 2 table and make this join it works fine and i can bind it to a datagrid view (in winforms) but how can i access to result data
by foreach (how can i access to row[0][1] like data tables)??

```
 void Testmethod()
  {
     IEnumerable<object> result;

       using (var context = new TestDBEntities())
        {


             result = (from a in context.Table1
                  join b in context.Table2
                      on a.ID equals b.Id
                  select new { b.Id ,b.name });
               }
     }
```

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly different of what you ask, but may serve as well.

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> result;
using (var context = new TestDBEntities())
{
    result = (from a in context.Table1
              join b in context.Table2 on a.Id equals b.Id
              select new { b.Id, b.name }).ToList();
}

foreach (dynamic resultEntry in result)
    Console.Out.WriteLine("ID:" + resultEntry.Id + " name: " + resultEntry.name);
```

I hope this is good enough ;)

Comment: this is a method and i want to return the result data var result works in using scope only :)

Comment: I changed the code to allow you to use result outside the using scope. You need to convert the linq query to a list to keep its result, and a dynamic instead of an object, which resoles at runtime, so it will know the fields of the query outside of the using scope.

Comment: @motevallizadeh I know it's been a long time, but could you consider accepting the answer? Thanks!